# JavaScript Preloader Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, preloader

I've been working on a website and I recently decided to implement a preloader to my website.
I have everything in place but the JavaScript to control the loader does not seem to work.

Here's my code:

As there's quite some code, I have uploaded it on JSFiddle
Here it is
https://jsfiddle.net/mvc2fe1a/1/

```
<div class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div class="spinner">
        <svg width="634" height="62" viewBox="0 0 634 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
        </svg>

    </div>
    </div>
```

```
.spinner-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```
function loadPage() {
    let timeout = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
    document.querySelector('.spinner-wrapper').style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.container').style.display = 'block'
}
```

However this code does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to include the JSFiddle!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" that could be a lot of things.

Comment: I added code instead

Comment: Also, there are no errors in the console

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what is happening instead?

Comment: I want the loader to fade out @Merijndk

Comment: In your JSFiddle loadpage() doesn't seem to be called?

Comment: what seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your `loadPage` function. Right now, you have only defined it.

```js
// other code
loadPage();
```

Comment: Dude you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `loadPage()` function

I edited your Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/woma7h83/